# Problems with setting a custom date in c

Tags: c, date, pointers, time, linked-list

I need the user to enter a date and I need to be able to compare the year of the date later, I thought this would be straightforward but I am now getting the error *expressions must be a modifiable value*, I tryed googling the error but cant find a solution to my problem, here is the code that causes the error below:

The struct where I want to store the date

```
struct node{

int data;
char name[20];
char address[20];
char depart[20];
int day,mounth,year;
char doj[15];
int salary;
char email[30];
struct node *next;

};
```

The function where I am getting the error:

```
void addToStart (struct node** head)
{
    struct node *newNode;
    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("\nEnter data for this node:\n");
    scanf("%d", &newNode->data);
    printf("\nEnter address:\n");
    scanf("%s", &newNode->address);
    printf("\nEnter department:\n");
    scanf("%s", &newNode->depart);
    printf("\nEnter Data Of Join(dd/mm/yyyy):\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &newNode->day, &newNode->mounth, &newNode->year);
    newNode->doj = validDate(newNode->day, newNode->mounth, newNode->year);
    printf("\nEnter Salary:\n");
    scanf("%d", &newNode->salary);
    printf("\nEnter email:\n");
    scanf("%s", &newNode->email);

    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (*head==NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
         newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode;

    }
    printf("%u,%u",&head,&newNode);
   // *first = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to 'head'
}
```

The method I use to create the date:

```
char * validDate(int dd, int mm, int yy)
{
 struct tm t;
 struct tm *info;
 time_t rawtime;
 info = localtime(&rawtime);
 char buffer[80];

 info->tm_mday   = dd;
 info->tm_mon    = mm;
 info->tm_year   = yy;

 strftime(buffer,80,"%x", info);
 return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Please post more code that shows how `newNode` is declared.

Comment: In `validDate(int dd, int mm, int yy)` you declared a pointer `struct tm *t;` but it does not point to anything before you try assigning values.

Comment: Thirdly, the `buffer` returned by `validDate` is a local variable that is destroyed when the function returns. Please declare it as `static char buffer[80];`

Comment: I've updated the code and changed the struct tm *t part, any idea whats wrong? I've never tryed to use date like this so Im a little confused

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() (and family of functions)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: always check the returned value (not the parameters) from scanf (and family of functions) to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.  When entering a %s string, always prefix the %s with a space so any left over white space (including a new line) is skipped.  When entering a %s string, always include a length modifier, otherwise the user can easily overflow the input buffer bounds, resulting in undefined behaviour, which can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding these two lines: ' printf("\nEnter Data Of Join(dd/mm/yyyy):\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &newNode->day, &newNode->mounth, &newNode->year);'  if the user follows the instructions and enters: '25/10/1946' then the scanf() will only pickup the 'day' and not the rest of the input because '/' is not white space.  Suggest: if( 3 != scanf( "%d/%d/%d",...) { //handle error } else ...

Comment: the function validDate() does not actually validate the day, month, year.  Rather it just concats them into a single string.   Validating a date has to validate the year (usually as being within a certain range, say 1900....2100.)  then, validate the month as being in the range 1...12.  Then, validate the day, given the month and year,  Usually by a table relating montNum to max days in month, and taking into consideration if it is a 'leap' year.  Never assume the user entered valid data so be sure to check for negative numbers and 0 as both are invalid values, maybe looping until valid entry

Comment: regarding the 'email'  is 30 characters really enough?  perhaps if only entering the username, but username@servername.ext might exceed 30 characters.  As previously mentioned, include a length modifier on the %s when reading the email value so the buffer is not overrun.

Comment: this line: 'newNode->doj = validDate(newNode->day, newNode->mounth, newNode->year);' copies some pointer, not the concatenated date string. suggest: 'strncpy( newNode->doj, validDate(newNode->day, newNode->mounth, newNode->year), sizeof( newNode->doj ) );

Comment: the struct has doj as only 12 characters, so the function validDate() should be limited to only producing a data string of max 12 characters, including the NUL terminator

Comment: regarding these two lines: 'time_t rawtime;
 info = localtime(&rawtime);' the 'rawtime' field has not been set, so contains garbage.  suggest inserting before call to 'localtime()'  'rawtime = time(NULL);'

Comment: the line: 'struct tm t;' is not used and should be eliminated

Answer (score 2):

Some errors I can see in your code :

- `scanf("%s", &newNode->address);` : newNode->address is a char array, which *decays* to a pointer => you **must not** add a `&` here. IMHO it is the cause of your error since an array is not a modifiable value. And as it has size `20`, you'd better limit the read to avoid a possible overflow (and the associated undefined behaviour). So the line should be :

  ```
  scanf("%19s", newNode->address);
  ```

  You should do same thing with all char arrays in your struct.
- `printf("\nEnter Data Of Join(dd/mm/yyyy):\n");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &newNode->day, &newNode->mounth, &newNode->year);`

  You ask for a value in format `dd/mm/yyyy` and do not put the `/` in read format. And you do not control the return value of scanf : if something goes wrong, you do not load correct values in struct members but are not warned of it. This last remark is general for all your `scanf` but here as you have an error in format, the control of the return value would warn you. Assuming `cr` is an int variable, the line should be :

  ```
  cr = scanf("%d/%d/%d", &newNode->day, &newNode->mounth, &newNode->year);
  if (cr != 3) {
      // wrong input ...
  }
  ```
- in `validDate` you return an automatic array (`char buffer[80];`). Never do that in C : you can only return a static array or a dynamic allocated one (with malloc). Because the automatic array is allocated on the stack and will be freed as soon as the function return leaving you with a dangling pointer.
- in `validDate` you call `localtime` on an unitialized value. You do not use the returned value, but you should not even call `localtime` and directly use `t`.
- in `validDate` you initialize `tm_mon` member with the month read. That's wrong : `tm_mon` varies from 0 to 11. You should have `info->tm_mon = mm - 1;`
- you write `newNode->doj = validDate(newNode->day, newNode->mounth, newNode->year);`, when `doj` is a `char[15]`. You cannot do that : as I already said, an array is not a modifiable value. You can either copy the string with `strncpy`:

  ```
  strncpy(newNode->doj, validDate(newNode->day, newNode->mounth, newNode->year), 15);
  ```

  or make `doj` a pointer :

  ```
  struct node{
  ...
  char *doj;
  ...
  };
  ```

Summary :

- arrays are not modifiable
- in scanf char arrays shall not use `&`
- arrays are not pointers (event if they *decay* to)
- allways test `scanf` return value
- beware of the `tm_mon` attribute of `struct tm` which varies from 0 to 11

Answer (score 0):

Over and above the problems mentioned by [Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29884064/15168), I see:

```
printf("\nEnter Data Of Join(dd/mm/yyyy):\n");
scanf("%d %d %d", &newNode->day, &newNode->mounth, &newNode->year);
```

You ask for the date to be separated by slashes, but the format only accepts blanks.  Your users are going to be confused!  Maybe you need something like:

```
if (scanf("%d%*[-/. ]%d%*[-/. ]%d", &newNode->day, &newNode->mounth, &newNode->year) != 3)
    …report error entering date and recover somehow…
```

This allows any of blank, `/`, `-` or `.` as the separator between the components of the date.  There isn't an easy way to accept alternative punctuation such as 2015-04-15 but reject mixed punctuation such as 2015-04/15.  The hard way is to read the two punctuation characters, rather than suppress the assignment with the `*`, and then compare them after the read is successful (but you then have 5 items that are scanned).

(Incidentally, month is normally spelled without a 'u', but you're consistent so it doesn't formally matter.)

Then you have the code:

```
char *validDate(int dd, int mm, int yy)
{
    struct tm t;
    struct tm *info;
    time_t rawtime;
    info = localtime(&rawtime);
    char buffer[80];

    info->tm_mday   = dd;
    info->tm_mon    = mm;
    info->tm_year   = yy;

    strftime(buffer, 80, "%x", info);
    return buffer;
}
```

Problems:

1. You need to initialize `rawtime` before you analyze it with `localtime()`.
2. The encoding of `tm_mon` and `tm_year` in a `struct tm` is odd:

   - `tm_mon` is 0 for January to 11 for December.
   - `tm_year` is the current year minus 1900.

   You need to compensate for these in your assignments:
3. You are returning a pointer to a local variable.
4. You don't use `t` at all.

Possible fixes:

```
char *validDate(int dd, int mm, int yy, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    time_t rawtime = time(0);
    struct tm *info = localtime(&rawtime);

    info->tm_mday   = dd;
    info->tm_mon    = mm - 1;
    info->tm_year   = yy - 1900;

    strftime(buffer, buflen, "%x", info);
    return buffer;
}
```

With this, you pass the buffer and its size into the function; you get back a pointer to the buffer you passed in.